# cvs annotate and standard error redirection

Tags: perl, ksh, cvs, stderr

First, some background. I'm trying to use `cvs annotate` within a Perl script invoked from a ksh command line to find out who's using bad hex constants in their source code and dole out justice appropriately. I'd like to use stdout for this program strictly for my own structured output, so I can pipe it to a file or to other programs. But, every call to cvs annotate results in a diagnostic message being printed to the console. It takes the form of:

```
Annotations for <filename>
***********
```

It's mucking up my stdout! I played around with annotate on the command line, and I figured that these diagnostic messages were coming from stderr, because running this command directly in ksh:

```
cvs annotate <filename> 1>yay.txt 2>boo.txt
```

correctly puts the desired annotated output into yay.txt and the diagnostics into boo.txt. However, things get weirder when I try to run this from within a perl script using backticks.

```
$muhstring = `cvs annotate $filename 2>boo.txt`;
```

The desired annotated output does appear in `$muhstring`, but the diagnostics still get printed to the command line, and boo.txt is created as an empty file. [There's an admittedly old post on perlmonks.org](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20can%20I%20capture%20STDERR%20from%20an%20external%20command?) that says this syntax should work as written. So, what's the deal? Is this a CVS quirk, have I misread the post, or have things changed since 1999? Or is it something else?

Edit: So, it is not, in fact, mucking up stdout. I tried this in ksh:

```
perl findbadhexowners.pl badhex.txt > out.txt
```

and the diagnostic messages still printed to the console, but out.txt only contains the annotations. This is fine for my purposes, and I can continue with other code.

That said, it seems like Perl and cvs specifically are interacting a little strangely, especially considering that redirection in ksh works fine and redirection in Perl *for other commands* like `cd` works fine - for example, in Perl

```
`cd nonexistentDir 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`;
```

gives the expected output in both stdout.txt and stderr.txt. It's only using `cvs annotate` from within Perl that produces this problem.

Comment: Does ```$muhstring = `cvs annotate $filename </dev/null 2>boo.txt`;``` fix the problem?  If yes, I have an explanation; if not, I don't.

Comment: That's odd. It works for me. http://pastebin.com/RbDrEmNF

Comment: BTW, I seem to have found a bug in `cvs annotate`. The output shows the wrong version of the `$Revision:` line. (And the fact that it prints to stderr with no option to turn it off is annoying. I had never noticed it because I always use `cvs annotate ... | less`.)

Comment: http://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/index.php?44537 (not directly relevant to your problem).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: @KeithThompson, what version of cvs are you using? What system?

Comment: @PaulBunch: CVS 1.12.13-MirDebian-11, Linux Mint 17.1. (The only reason that would matter is if older versions of CVS print that message to stdout. I'll look into that.) What version are you using?

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry that I can't help.  I don't have sufficient (read any) experience with `cvs`.

Comment: The oldest version I can find sources for, 1.11.17, prints that message to stderr. And that wouldn't explain your symptom anyway, since it works correctly when you type the command directly in ksh. Are you running `cvs annotate` on the same file, in the same directory, both times? Are you invoking the same `cvs` command (check `$PATH`)? Is the repository local or remote? What's in `CVS/Root`?

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, same file, same directory. I'm using CVS 1.11.23. I think this is Red Hat 6.4. As for local or remote repositories...I'm really not sure. I've only been using CVS for about a week. I'm not sure how to look in CVS/Root.

Comment: Is the repository local or remote? What's in `CVS/Root`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No worries! I've only been using it for about a week, myself.

Comment: I've created a gist (a small Github repo) with a test script that attempts to reproduce the problem. When I run it on my system, it behaves correctly. Please try running the script on your system and report the results. https://gist.github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/ff58b260bbe2c59e9161

Comment: It's been a while. Have you had a chance to try the script?

Comment: I'm actually a little nervous to try it since I don't entirely understand what it does, and I'm working in a big shared repository on a large project. I want to make sure I don't do anything I don't know how to undo.

Comment: @KeithThompson Re old versions ... see https://github.com/rdebath/test/tree/cvs (for now)

Comment: I suppose there could be something odd with the filename, so how about trying the command `cvs 2>boo.txt annotate $filename` instead.

Comment: @PaulBunch: The script creates a temporary CVS repo under your home directory (and tells you how to delete it afterwards). It will not touch your shared repo.